# Unable to set automatically image slide in android Fragment

Tags: android

In my app I want an image slider.I already do that with view pager but I want image change automatically in every 2seconds. I am unable to do that.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container,false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this.getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    indicator = (CircleIndicator) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    return rootView;
}
```

this is my fragment class.

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] image_resource = {R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resource.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return (view == object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageview.setImageResource(image_resource[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}
}
```

this is my adapter class.I want that image change automatically.Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code I had written a really long time ago which does something similar, maybe this can help you.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable update = () -> {
        if (currentPage == list.size()) {
            currentPage = 0;
        }
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(update);
        }
    }, 2500, 2500);


   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

       timer.cancel();

   }
```

So you set a timer which gets called after a certain interval of time (~2.5 seconds here) and when it does, you check if the current page of the adapter has reached the end then reset it back to 0 else increment it.

Comment: Looking at this code now, I realise there is no need for a timer and a simple handler with a `postDelayed` should easily be able to handle this task.